# Visualizando categorias exclusivas de Custom Post Types

Tags: wordpress

Eu criei um *Custom Post Type*, mas agora não estou conseguindo criar categorias que sejam vista apenas para esse CPT.

Ao adicionar `'taxonomies' => array('category')`, ele exibe todas as categorias. Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Usei o seguinte código antes do **register_post_type** e funcionou! Esta ai para quem tiver a mesma dúvida.

---

```
 register_taxonomy( 'images', 
    array('images'), /* This is the name of your custom post type, I used "Images" */
    array('hierarchical' => true,     /* if this is true it acts like categories */             
        'labels' => array(
             /* OPTIONS */
        ),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
    )
);    

register_post_type( 'images',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Images' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'images' ),
            'add_new' => __('New', 'Image'),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'images/test','with_front' => FALSE)
    )
);
```

Comment: tenho um problema similar, porém meu custom post type não tem funcionado a taxonomia que seria as categorias http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15052/wp-custom-post-type/15175?noredirect=1#15175 http://pastebin.com/kKgPTyQJ

Answer (score 1):

Para quem não entendeu a solução:

O problema estava em usar um taxonomy reservado pelo WordPress, no caso **category**, ao usar **images** funcionou normalmente.

Comment: Você devia comentar (ou editar) na resposta dele ao invés de criar uma nova. ;)