# WP Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

O correto seria ter o mesmo comportamento do `"Category"` do post type `"post"` do wordpress, mas isso não acontece.

Por exemplo quando eu acesso `http://localhost/projeto/anunciantes/` tenho como fazer minhas queries normalmente para personalizar minhas exibições, mas quando acesso `http://localhost/projeto/anunciantes/categoria/sub-categoria/enfim...` ele me mostra erro 404, mesmo eu tendo deixado `'hierarchical' => true,`

Não consigo entender o que está acontecendo

```
register_taxonomy( 'anunciante_category', array( 'anunciante' ), array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => __( 'Categoria Anunciantes' ),
            'labels' => array( // Labels customizadas
            'name' => _x( 'Categorias', 'Categorias' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Categoria', 'Categoria' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Pesquisar Categorias' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'Todas Categorias' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Categoria Pai' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Categoria Pai:' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Editar Categoria' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Atualizar Categoria' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Adicionar Nova Categoria' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'Nome Nova Categoria' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Categorias' ),
        ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_tag_cloud' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'anunciantes',//anunciantes/categorias
                'with_front' => true,
            ),
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'hierarchical' => true,
```

Trata como páginas pelo que entendi você gostaria de usar como post e suas categorias.

Você precisa colocar como:

```
'hierarchical' => false,
```

E criar uma taxonomia para isso.

Algo como:

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function custom_taxonomy() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Taxonomies', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Taxonomy', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Taxonomy', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used items', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => false,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy', array( 'teste' ), $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Lembrando que no trecho a baixo a palavra teste é seu CPT:

```
register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy', array( 'teste' ), $args );
```

Referenciando assim aonde será utilizado.

Comment: é exatamente assim que está minha função atual para o custom post type http://pastebin.com/kKgPTyQJ estou analisando o que me respondeu

Comment: tenta deixar a nomenclatura do CPT e da Taxonomia diferentes, gera menos trabalho debugando problemas.

Comment: mas o CPT é anunciante e a TAXONOMIA é anunciante_category

Comment: 'hierarchical' => true, precisa ser false pois true é igual a pagina e false igual a post

Comment: eu testei com o false, mas pelo que tenho visto precisa deixar true pra ele seguir as categorias filhas

Comment: e outra se eu deixar como 'hierarchical' => false fica tudo como categoria pai, e não é isso que pretendo

Comment: pelo que li false é como post aonde funciona certinho e true como paginas

Comment: a questão é que nenhuma das formas funciona conforme tem de funcionar, mas quando o valor é setado true ele transforma tudo em categoria pai, e isso não é válido

Comment: Se for mais pratico https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Comment: estou evitando o uso desnecessário de plugins, mas caso não consiga fazer funcionar de outra forma, eu verifico a possibilidade de usa-lo

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MKicRBPh

Comment: esse ai é um teste

Comment: Ainda não consegui uma solução ... funciona de forma inadequada

Comment: o que seria inadequado ?

Comment: a minha taxonomia anunciantes_category não funciona como as categorias do `posts` por exemplo

Comment: muito estranho isso ai ontem mesmo precisei e acabei criando da mesma forma que te passei e esta funcionando normalmente

Comment: você viu meu código completo do pastebin ? http://pastebin.com/kKgPTyQJ não consigo visualizar o erro :/

Comment: slug de ambos esta igual podendo gerar o erro todo